# Running "top" memory seems high?

Tags: ubuntu, memory, top

I'm not a Ubuntu expert, but I've just ran `top` on a Ubuntu server box and Terminal has highlighted the results in red, it looks pretty high to me.

[image]

Is this right? I'm only really running Apache and Node.js on there. What can I do to bring down the memory?

Comment: I've marked this question as a duplicate of our canonical question about how Unix systems report memory utilization. If you believe this is not a duplicate please update your question with additional details (the full output of `top` sorted by resident size (`RES`) is a good starting point) and it may be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

Don't rely on `top` to tell you how much free memory you have. Use something like `free -m`. The way Linux uses (and reports on) memory is that it puts most of the "free" memory into buffer. This results in Top thinking that the memory is used when it reality it's not actually being used and is available for processes that need it.